# Any thoughts: page called/loaded 700 times

Tags: php, javascript

This might be a long shot, but I'm going to put it on here anyway.

I have a (very, very rarely occurring) problem in my application, particularly when users send e-mail (but that might be because that's the most-used feature). The page that actually sends the e-mail in my application is sometimes (has only been reported by one user) called up to 700 times! This obviously leads to a very embarrassing 700 e-mails in the inbox of their business relation. The last time, the 700 calls, were made in a period of around 5 minutes.

Any clues on how this could possibly occur? Browsers, javascript, plug-ins?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the accesslogs, to see if the page generating the mails actually are requested that many times?

Comment: This is not answerable and barely qualifies as on-topic. You've provided no information about the server, the server-environment and the client-environment. All we can do is guess...

Comment: Someone sleeping on the F5 key? I'm sorry, but I cannot find out what might be the problem without any code. Are you sure you aren't using any while loops without exiting them appropriately?

Comment: +1 for sleeping suggestion ;)

Comment: Sorry guys, I already said it might be a long shot. I'm not looking for code solutions, just thoughts to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was indeed a page that stayed open and for some reason (I'm thinking browser plugin) it kept sending the e-mails. The page didn't need to be opened but Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Without more detail, preferably example code, it's very hard to suggest the most likely reason.

Does the page that sends the email then attempt to redirect to another page?  If so, perhaps it's accidentally redirecting to itself, causing the browser to keep re-requesting the same page?

Comment: great suggestion, sadly I can't find the multiple-redirect in the access logs so that's probably not it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say some bug in your code that sens email 700 times under some circumstances...

Answer (score 1):

Is it exactly 700 every time, or does the number of emails vary? As the answers before suggest, you should first check, whether your page is actually called 700 times (which would point to some kind of a redirect running wild) or if the page is only called once (which would point to some kind of bug in your email sending routine).

Comment: Nope, the numbers vary. The access logs don't show any unusual data either. I'm thinking some plugin might have screwed something up? It's occurred some 3 times and 3 times with the same user.